# How to display embedded PDF in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem displaying PDF which is embedded into HTML page in Internet Explorer 10 and 11. I've tried different ways and didn't find a solution.

This code works in IE10 and FireFox, but not in IE11:

```
<body>
    <object id="pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600"
        height="250" data="Form1.pdf"></object>
</body>
```

This code works in FireFox, but doesn't work in IE10 and IE11:

```
<body>
    <div id="placeholder">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var obj = $("<object>", { id: "pdf", type: "application/pdf",
                width: "600", height: "250" });
            obj.attr("data", "Form1.pdf");
            $("#placeholder").append(obj);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

And this code works in IE10 and FireFox, but it still doesn't work in IE11:

```
<body>
    <object id="template" type="application/pdf" width="600"
        height="250" style="display: none"></object>
    <div id="placeholder">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var obj = $('#template').clone();
            obj.attr("data", "Form1.pdf");
            obj.show();
            $("#placeholder").append(obj);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

So I'm wondering if there is any way to display embedded PDF in IE11? Or the only solution is to convert PDF to image on server side and send this image to client?

P.S. Software I used for tests:

1. Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16476 on Windows 7 (Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled)
2. Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16746 on Windows Server 2012 R2
3. Adobe Reader 11.0.5 (Protected Mode is disabled)

Comment: Is there any console output when you try this in IE11?

Comment: Have you tried embedding the content using an IFrame?

Comment: No, just "HTML1300: Navigation occurred."

Comment: No, I didn't try iframe. Will do. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pdf.js. It works fine for me on all modern browsers(supporting HTML5). If you use PDF.js, you can get content from pdf easily as its just a viewer written in pure js. BTW who still uses IE browsers?

Comment: I've tried IFRAME, both "static" and dynamically created. Unfortunately, this was also didn't work. IE11 asked me to download the file.

Comment: Surprisingly, PDFJS works for FF, Chrome and both IE10 and 11. But unfortunately it's a research project, so I think currently it's just a thing to play with, not a solution. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Surprisingly, all code above plus IFRAME plus PDF.JS works in the IE11-on-Win7 virtual machine which I've just downloaded from the http://www.modern.ie/ web site. So, it looks like the problem is on my laptop (domain security policy etc.) So, I'm going to dig deeper into it.